# After I added a parameter to the route, for all images in page I got error : not found resource error

Tags: jquery, laravel, routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYCsR.png)

I have a page for show a list (online courses). For every course, I show title, ... and image. Everything was well.

After I added a parameter to route for this page, all images got error : not found resource.

```
<!--in menu:-->
                            
@if (isset($userInfo) And ($userInfo->role == 'admin' or $userInfo->role == 'teacher'))
<!-- old ahref link -->
<!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="\courses_panel"> -->

<!-- new ahref link -->
<a class="dropdown-item" href="\courses_panel\{{$userInfo->id}}">
  Cources Management Panels
</a>                              
@endif   

<!--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<!--in web.php-->
<!--the last route : -->
<!--Route::get('/courses_panel', 'CoursesPanel@index');-->

<!--new -->
<?php
Route::get('/courses_panel/{id}','CoursesPanel@index')
   ->name('Courses_panel');
?>

<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<!-- in controller -->

<!-- I just add parameter and where -->
<?php
    public function index($userId)
    {
        $courses = Course::where('course_author' , '=' , $userId)->get();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('courses_panel' , compact("courses" , 'categories'));
    }
?>
<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<!-- in courses Page -- without change-->

@foreach ($courses as $course)
           <img class="rounded img-responsive courseImage" 
src="images/{{$course->course_image}}" alt="" name="" > 
@endforeach
```

Comment: without the leading `/` your image path became `/courses_panel/images/{{$courseImage}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is how you are you are defining your image path in the `<img>` tag

Try an absolute path (leading `/`)

```
<img class="rounded img-responsive courseImage" src="{{asset('/images/'.$course->course_image)}}" alt="" name="" >
```

Explanation:

**Case 1:**

if the `src attribute` is not leading with `/` for example `images/test.png`, the link to that image will depend on the `URL` of the page **you are on**

`http://www.example.com/` => `http://www.example.com/images/test.png`

`http://www.example.com/some_page` => `http://www.example.com/images/test.png`

`http://www.example.com/some_page/sub_page` => `http://www.example.com/some_page/images/test.png`

`http://www.example.com/some_page/sub_page/` => `http://www.example.com/some_page/sub_page/images/test.png`

**Case 2:**

if the `src attribute` is leading with `/` for example `/images/test.png`, the link to that image will **NOT** depend on the `URL` of the page **you are on** but it can break domains that have ports in the url

`http://www.example.com/some_page/sub_page/` => `http://www.example.com/images/test.png`

`http://localhost:6080/some_page/sub_page/` => `http://localhost/images/test.png`

**Best practice**

To avoid all that, it's better to write the public path of the image with the complete domain `//example.com/images/test.png`. That way it will work every time.

You will notice that the path starts with double slash `//`, that way it will be:

`http://example.com/images/test.png` if you are on a `http://` page

and

`https://example.com/images/test.png` if you are on a `https://` page

**Laravel**

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); // http://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg
$url = secure_asset('img/photo.jpg'); // https://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg
```

more info in the documentation [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) , [secure_asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-secure-asset)

ps: if `asset()` is called from `CLI` environment it will use the `env` variable `APP_URL` to build the link

Comment: No , It doesnot work. Actually this is the error : GET http://localhost:8000/courses_panel/images/1943762341.jpg 404 (Not Found)

where this is the correct path for images:
http://localhost:8000/images/1943762341.jpg

I dont know why "courses_panel/" added to all img srcs.

Comment: @MohammadWebMaster i've edited my answer, use the asset helper so it will convert it to an absolute link

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. But can you explain me more what is differnce between absolute linke and a normal link?

Comment: @MohammadWebMaster i've added some explanation and a best practice without going into details of the `asset()` method of laravel

Comment: It is great. Thank you so much.