# Trailing backslash in SvelteJs routes - Changing Request Urls of static assets in public folder

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup

So, I have a component in Svelte, which is supposed to get rendered in the route = `property/:propId`

This component is responsible for fetching a property by id and display them on the client.

But the issue, That I am facing is, in svelte -> as soon as in add a trailing `/` to the route, all request URLs for static assets are also changing. Which is causing the images/icons to break.

Like, as soon as I add `property/` to the route, and render that component, requests for images/icons are going to `property/Images/Chat.png` and giving me `404` bc, that route doesn't exist, and all my images are stored inside `Public/Images/`

But without the trailing slash, the images/icons are rightly fetched from `/Images/Chat.png` w.r.t to the Public folder

Does anyone know any fix or workarounds?

Comment: note: backslash is \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up the router/server to normalize URLs, i.e. always add or remove the slash, or to just use [absolute paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls) for the resources (`/Public/Images/...` - start with a `/`).

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: No, regarding paths you can check the link to learn more and you have not even specified what router or server you use, so I cannot tell you anything more about how to do route normalization. (Though even even if you provide that information, you should just search how to do that yourself first.)

Comment: adding `/` in front helped reso;lve the resource not found error . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This article helped : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377376/after-i-added-a-parameter-to-the-route-for-all-images-in-page-i-got-error-not/57377436#57377436]

For anyone, who's facing the same, error, hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377376/after-i-added-a-parameter-to-the-route-for-all-images-in-page-i-got-error-not/57377436#57377436